# Using OAuth tokens to authorize different ASP.NET MVC Applications from Single Sign On Source

Tags: asp.net, oauth

I have a number of different web applications, all running in ASP.NET MVC.  These ASP.NET MVC applications are .NET/Angular hybrids and generally call into WebAPI APIs which run in their own separate application on IIS.

All applications are on the same domain,but in separate subdomains. They all run on the same instance of IIS.

The structure looks something like this:

- Payments Application (*MVC, payments.myapp.com*)
- News Application (*MVC, news.myapp.com*)
- Payments API (*WebAPI, paymentsapi.myapp.com*)
- News API (*WebAPI, newsapi.myapp.com*)
- Login Application (*MVC, login.myapp.com*)
- Login API (*WebAPI, loginapi.myapp.com*)

What I need to be able to do is log in to the Payments and News Applications from one single source, i.e. the Login Application.  The login application then calls into a login API (which is obviously not restricted) to issue a token.

If the user tries to access the Payments or News Applications without a token then they should be redirected to the login application.  The Payments API and NewsAPIs should also be inaccessible without a valid token, which should be set at the same time login happens.

Currently, the login API issues a bearer token successfully using OWIN/OAuth - the part I am unsure about is using this across subdomains.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Asp.Net built in Owin Authentication middle ware to achieve this functionality. Please refer to this great [article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/) and I am sure you will come up with the solution that fits your needs.

Write an extension method on IAppBuilder in a seperate class library and share that across all of your applications for token validation . See the following as an example (code copied from the article):

```
public static void ConfigureOAuth(this IAppBuilder app)        
{
            var issuer = "http://jwtauthzsrv.azurewebsites.net";
            var audience = "099153c2625149bc8ecb3e85e03f0022";
            var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("IxrAjDoa2FqElO7IhrSrUJELhUckePEPVpaePlS_Xaw");

            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                    }
                });

        }
```

Issuer will issue the token using the same information (secret and audience). Since the validation logic is same across the sub-domains, the token will be valid on all sub-domains.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've implemented the functionality in this article, but it doesn't address the issue of using the token across domains.

Comment: Since you have Login application separate, you could use that as the Authorization Server. This would be even better option. Here is a [link](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/) from the same blog on how that works. Please let me know if you have any specific concerns and I will try to clear that as much as I could. Thank you.